# Font Awesome icons disappear after refresh in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Bootstrap version 3

Font Awesome version 3.2.1

I am having issues with bootstrap and font awesome on Chrome. When I originally load a page, the font awesome icons are displayed correctly. When I refresh the page, the icons disappear. **To clarify, the entire icon is missing, this is not the empty box issue that some others encounter.

I'm grasping at straws here, but I noticed there were differences in the order in which the files were retrieved between the original page load and the refresh.

When the page is refreshed, the font file is the last item to be retrieved, and it appears to be a cached version as well.

Finally, any icons that are located inside of a `<div class="btn">` will be loaded when the mouse hovers over the `div`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Initial page load
[image: Original page load]

[image: Original page load headers]

Page refresh
[image: Page refresh]

[image: Page refresh headers]

Comment: Are you able to replicate this on another machine. Better yet, not a different network?

Comment: Yes, I first noticed it when I connected via remote desktop to another machine.

Comment: Is this happening only when you are using remote desktop?

Comment: No, it happens on my computer as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are on a Windows machine, right?

This is an old problem with Chrome. See [this posting](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/issue-with-icon-fonts-in-chrome-23/) on CSS Tricks. The next to last post should be the answer to your question. Or in short: Use the PUA (Private Use Area) for encoding.

The Unicodes (PUA codes) for each icon are listed in the [Font Awesome CSS file](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css) - see: Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA)... (around line 190).

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem in latest verion of chrome (33.0.1750.152)
Working solution for me: move styles from body to head section.